# R: Function returns both error and warning - store both with tryCatch()

Tags: r, url, error-handling, try-catch

I am using `readLines()` in `[R]` and for some URLs, it gives me errors, together with a warning message:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open: HTTP status was '401 Unauthorized'
```

As you can see, the function returns both a generic error and a more specific explanation in the warning. Currently, I am using `tryCatch()` and some lines to print and store these errors using `conditionMessage()`. However, this only stores the generic uninformative eroror message while I'm actually more interested in the warning text. How can I store both?

Working example:

```
errorlist <- NULL

for(i in 1:10){
tryCatch({
readLines("http://www.googl1.com/") # this URL does not exist
}, error = function(e){yy
  print(conditionMessage(e))
  assign("errorlist", c(errorlist, conditionMessage(e)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
})}
```

Desired outcome would be something like:

```
      [,1]                     [,2]                                              
 [1,] "cannot open connection" "The server name or address could not be resolved"
 [2,] "cannot open connection" "The server name or address could not be resolved"
 [3,] "cannot open connection" "The server name or address could not be resolved"
 [4,] "cannot open connection" "The server name or address could not be resolved"
 [5,] "cannot open connection" "The server name or address could not be resolved"
 [6,] "cannot open connection" "The server name or address could not be resolved"
 [7,] "cannot open connection" "The server name or address could not be resolved"
 [8,] "cannot open connection" "The server name or address could not be resolved"
 [9,] "cannot open connection" "The server name or address could not be resolved"
[10,] "cannot open connection" "The server name or address could not be resolved"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could turn the warning into in error, with

```
options(warn=2)
```

On the other hand, this would only return the warning (as error) in `tryCatch`.

Comment: It definitely works, thanks, but then I would have to remember to switch to `warn = 0` again when I use other functions which I want to behave differently. Moreover, as you indicate, it will suppress the original error message.